# SSIS Transfer Object Task Timeout

Tags: ssis, entity-framework-6, etl, data-warehouse, biml

I can see I'm not the only person who's experienced an issue with the SSIS Transfer Database Object Task and timeouts, however, people using this for the extract phase of an ETL must be something fairly common, so I'm trying to establish what is the usual/accepted way to  do this.

I have a web application that uses Entity Framework to generate ~250 tables, some of which occasionally have schema updates.

The bulk of the transform and load portion of our ETL is handled by a series of stored procedures, however, these read from a copy of the application's tables that are initially loaded in the Transfer Database Objects task.

Initially, we set up an SSIS package that simply ran the Transfer Database Objects task, and then kicked off the stored proc.  That meant that the job was fairly resilient to change, and the only changes required were changes to the stored proc, if and when a schema update affected the tables that were used therein.

Unfortunately, as one of our application instances has grown over time, the Transfer Database Objects task is reaching the point where I'm regularly seeing Timeout errors.  Those don't appear to be connection timeouts, or anything I can control on the server side, and from what I can see, I can't amend the CommandTimeout on the underlying SMO stuff within that Task.

I can see that some people manually craft their extract, such that they run a separate Data Flow task to pull the information from each table, which has the obvious bonus that these can be run in parallel, however, in my case, that's going to mean an initial chunk of work to craft 250ish of these, and a maintenance task whenever the schema changes on the source database, no matter how minor.

I've come across Biml, which looked like a possible way to at least ease that overhead, however, it doesn't appear this can run on VS2017 yet.

Does anyone have any particular patterns they follow for this, or if I do need individual data flow tasks, is there some way to automate the schema update, perhaps using some kind of SSIS automation and something from the entity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the easiest way around this is to write a clone of the Transfer task, but with appropriate additions to allow more control over batching and timeouts etc. Details are available in this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2007/04/18/roll-your-own-transfer-sql-server-objects-task/